# How do I write multiple lists to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write two different lists into pair columns in a csv file, but when I execute the code, I get an error.

I wrote code to go through a file directory, grab/split the file names with Regex into list variables, then I want to write those values to a csv file in two separate columns. I can get the code to work with a single for loop, but I can't get it to do both lists.

```py
import os
import csv
import re

path = r"D:\Documents\Python_test\\"

files = []
csv_filename = "python_list_test.csv"
fd = []
fn = []
#r = root, d = directory, f = files

for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for name in f:
        if '.txt' in name:
            files.append(name)
            split_string = re.split('(\A[0-9]{6})', name)
            fd.append(split_string[1])
            fn.append(split_string[2])

with open(csv_filename,mode='w',newline='') as c:
    writer = csv.writer(c)
    writer.writrow(['Date','File Name',])

    writer.writrows([i] for i in fd,[e] for e in fn)
```

I get an error code:

```
 File "C:/Users/[FILE NAME].py", line 25 writer.writrows^([i] for i in fd,[e] for e in fn)

SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(fd, fn))
```

Comment: Will do. What does the zip function do?

Comment: The zip() function returns an iterator of tuples based on the iterable object. More info here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: It's an in-built function of python3. It makes an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterable. You can find more about it here.[link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Ok, so in doing that, I get a blank row in between each correctly output row. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it get it to work with the following code, but I don't know if it's the best way to do it, or if I should be worried about efficiency:

```
    for name in f:
        if '.txt' in name:
            files.append(name)
            split_string = re.split('(\A[0-9]{6})', name)
            fd.append(split_string[1])
            fn.append(split_string[2])

            with open(csv_filename,mode='a',newline='') as c:
                writer = csv.writer(c)
                writer.writerow([split_string[1],split_string[2]])
```